# Do resistors turn electricity into heat?

Tags: resistors, heat

When wiring resistors to a battery, it generates heat and in the worst case, sets on fire but when it is used to limit current, for example in series to an LED, do they still generate heat ?

Comment: Do you think resistors know what they are wired to?

Comment: They must do : they have a very good relationship with current and voltage ... :)

Comment: @SolarMike That's why they say "I don't care what I am wired to, I only care about my friends Voltage and Current!"

Comment: A small effort in terms of a search on here would have found you this : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/387826/152903

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  This is *really basic* physics.

Voltage times current is power, which a resistor turns into heat.

From the above and Ohm's law, you can find the power dissipated by a resistor from its resistance and either the voltage across it or the current thru it.  In common units:

W = V A

W = V<sup>2</sup> / Ω

W = A<sup>2</sup> Ω

where W is power in Watts, V is EMF in Volts, A is current in Amperes, and Ω is resitance in Ohms.

Answer (score 9):

Technically they turn *electrical energy* into heat energy.

No electrons go missing or get converted into heat, but they carry less energy when they leave the resistor than they did on the way in; that energy has become heat.

Answer (score 3):

This is why they are called **resistor** because they resist the normal motion of charge carriers, electrons. In other words, they reduce current flow in a circuit, among other uses they have. So one consequence is generation of heat, which, intuitively, turns out to be due to friction between free electrons and atoms.

Comment: Saying a resistor *reduces current flow* in the general case is a very poor mental model at best, downright wrong at worst.